# Declare object property in a Class - Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js

In a JS version i would write it as:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: {}
    }
  }
}
```

But in a class style component using `vue-property-decorator`:

```
@Component
export default class Login extends Vue {
  public title: string = 'something'
}
```

I can set strings/numbers, but how to set an object?

`users` object would look like this:

```
{
  response: {
    users: [
      {
        user_email: '1@example.com',
        user_password: 'password'
      },
      {
        user_email: '2@example.com',
        user_password: 'password'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `public users: Record<string, User> = {}` or `public users: Array<User> = []` depending on what you want users to be

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, could you explain, what is `Record<string, User>`, `User` is an interface?

Comment: `User` would be the interface for the user you define (ie `interface User { id: string, name: string, notPasswordSoDontLook: string }`. `Record<string, T>` is an type that can be accessed with any string, and returns a `User`. There is not enough info to what you want to put in `users` so I took a guess at what the type should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const DEFAULT_OBJECT: ObjectType = {
        prop1: "value1",
        prop2: "value2
    };
```

Here's how you declare and initialize an object:

```
public myObject: ObjectType = DEFAULT_OBJECT;
```

Here's how you accept an object as prop:

```
@Prop({ default: () => (DEFAULT_OBJECT) })
public myObject: ObjectType;
```

In your case, you need to define an interface for User like this:

```
interface User {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

const DEFAULT_USERS: User[] = [
    {
        email: 'a@b.coom',
        password: 'abc'
    },
    {
        email: 'b@b.coom',
        password: 'abc1'
    }
];
```

And then, in your component, declare your users property like below:

```
export default class UserDetails extends Vue {
    public users: User[] = DEFAULT_USERS;
}
```

Comment: Can i just `public users: User[]` then in `constructor` assign its value?

Comment: You can initialise it with empty array like this  `public users: User[] = []`and then assign it its value at any point of time in future (created/mounted hooks or in any other methods).

Comment: I just tried to modify interface types, like setting up `email: number` and i didn't have any errors. Does it work at all?

Comment: If you change the data type in interface and if object having a type as that interface has a value of different data type, it throws typescript error. Whether your editor show you its an error or not depends on typescript configuration.

Comment: But if data is fetched from API, how would it know, what kind of data i received (i mean editor)?

Comment: That's why you define interfaces. You will give 'any' as a type to api response because you don't know what is its data type going to be, then parse the data in to an object whose type is determined by the interface you define and use that object everywhere. Since that parsed object is typed, you will get error if you try to assign different data type values to it than what it was expecting.

Comment: For example, i put fetched data in my users property: `this.users = response.data.users`, then i'm storing fetched data in `users` property, but it's not type checked somehow. What i'm doing wrong?